# What is the point of "grep -q"

Tags: linux, bash, grep, gnu

I was reading the `grep` manual page and came across the `-q` option, which tells `grep` to "not write anything to standard output. Exit immediately with zero status if any match is found, even if an error was detected."

I don't understand why this could be desirable or useful behavior. In a program whose raison d'être seems to be read from stdin, process, write to stdout, why would I want to silence it completely?

In what case would silencing a program whose goal it is to output things be useful? Why would someone want to entirely ignore errors and force a successful return code?

Comment: Besides its output streams, an executable has another way to communicate information : its exit status. For `grep` for instance it would be `0` if it matched something and something else otherwise. You could rely on this status to check whether a file contains a string or not, and if that's all you care about then it makes sense to suppress the output

Comment: Also, consider the `-c` option. Sometimes you don't care about *which* lines match, just *how many* match. From there, it's easier to imagine a further simplification where you don't even care *exactly* how many lines match, just the difference between 0 and >0 matches.

Comment: Moreover, this is a lot faster than a regular grep invocation, since it can exit immediately when the first match is found, rather than needing to unconditionally read (and write) to the end of file.

Comment: So exit status would be output even with the -q option provided?

Comment: -q only tells grep to not output anything to "standard output" but EVERY program that runs must have a return-value (at least in Unix-systems). Languages like C allow for the omission of explicitly writing it out, but the program will still have a return-value.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The exit status of `grep` doesn't necessarily indicate an *error* ; it indicates *success* or *failure*. `grep` defines success as matching 1 or more lines. Failure includes matching zero lines, *or* some other error that prevented matching from taking place in the first place.

`-q` is used when you don't care about which lines matched, only that *some* lines matched.

```
if grep -q foo file.txt; then
    echo "file.txt contains foo"
else
    echo "file.txt does not contain foo"
fi
```

Comment: To make sure I understand; this is for when it's called as a function, and you want its return code?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "as a function", but in the example shown, you aren't interested in seeing the lines containing the word `foo`, only in knowing they exist.

Comment: And how would you know if they exist if you silence all output from grep?

Comment: Because the exit status is different, and that's what `if` looks at.

Comment: Okay, Thanks! Looks like I should go read up on exit statuses. Do you know any good documentation that would help?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of `grep -q`: scanning the output of a command for a particular value, then performing an action if the value is found:

```bash
if docker context ls | grep -q dm-manager; then
  docker context rm dm-manager
fi
```

If the list of docker contexts contains `dm-manager` then remove docker context `dm-manager`.

Comment: I don't really see that this adds anything over the accepted answer.